# IF UPDATE RETURNS no rows been updated INSERT data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I would like to UPDATE records if they exist otherwise INSERT values into the table in one query for my Java project.

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS
(SELECT 1 NOTES WHERE USER_ID = '2' AND EVENT_ID ='4') THEN 
UPDATE NOTES SET NOTES='MY notes' WHERE USER_ID = '2' AND EVENT_ID ='4' 
ELSE 
INSERT INTO NOTES VALUES
((SELECT max(NOTES_ID)+1 FROM NOTES), '4, 2','1',''); END IF; END 
$do$
```

This is what I have until now however since Postgres 9.5 something must have changes and I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ELSE"
LINE 7: ELSE
```

Comment: Why not use [INSERT...ON CONFLICT UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql) if you're working with 9.5+?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon before the `else`

Comment: I hope you are not trying to generate unique IDs using that anti-pattern with the `max() + 1`. That will **not** work with concurrent inserts. Use a sequence if you want unique IDs

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. You can use the new [UPSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) syntax, `EXISTS` (just fix the semicolon as Clodoaldo mentioned) or using `FOUND` variable:

```
DO $do$
BEGIN
     UPDATE NOTES SET NOTES='MY notes' WHERE USER_ID = '2' AND EVENT_ID ='4';
     IF NOT FOUND THEN
          INSERT INTO NOTES VALUES ((SELECT max(NOTES_ID)+1 FROM NOTES), '4, 2','1','');
     END IF;
END $do$;
```

But beware of [racing conditions](https://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a PL/pgSQL block.

This can be done with a single SQL statement using writeable CTE:

```
with updated as (
  UPDATE NOTES 
    SET NOTES='MY notes' 
  WHERE USER_ID = 2 
    AND EVENT_ID = 4
  returning *
)
INSERT INTO NOTES (notes_id, event_id, user_id, notes)
select (SELECT max(NOTES_ID)+1 FROM NOTES), --<< Do NOT do this!!
       4,
       2, 
       'My notes'
where not exists (select * from updated);
```

Note that generating "unique" IDs using `max(notes_id) + 1` is not safe for concurrent usage and will not scale well if the table size increase.

Also: you should use numeric literals for numbers, not strings. `2` is a number `'2'` is a string.

If you have a unique index on `(user_id, event_id)` (which you should given the nature of your question) you can also use `insert on conflict` which was introduced in Postgres 9.5

```
INSERT INTO NOTES (notes_id, event_id, user_id, notes)
VALUES (
    (SELECT max(NOTES_ID)+1 FROM NOTES), --<< Do NOT do this!
    4, 2, 'My notes')
ON CONFLICT (user_id, event_id) 
  DO UPDATE set notes = excluded.notes;
```

---

A word of warning:

If you want to generate unique IDs in a **reliable**, concurrency-safe and scalable way you **have** to use a sequence. Do ***NOT*** use the anti-pattern `max() + 1`